# Escaping special characters in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, special-characters

I have a SQL Server table with department names in it (I.e. `Admissions & Registration`, `Women's Softball coach`) and when you click a link on our page it pulls all employees under that department however when you pull the `Women's Softball coach` I get an error as below:

> PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: >message: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 's'. (severity 15) in >C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DACC\directory\dept.php on line 179
>
> PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: >message: Unclosed quotation mark before the character string ') ORDER BY Lastname'. >>>(severity 15) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DACC\directory\dept.php on line 179
>
> PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: >Query failed in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DACC\directory\dept.php on line 179
>
> PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Line 5: Incorrect syntax near 's'. (severity 15) in >C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DACC\directory\dept.php on line 195
>
> PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: >message: Unclosed quotation mark before the character string '
>   ORDER BY directory.LastName'. (severity 15) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\DACC\directory\dept.php >on line 195

I know this is an issue with escaping special characters but is there a way to do that in the query or do I have to do it in the table?

The code referenced above is here--->

```
$department = $_GET['dept'];

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($department)) {

 // Send a select query to MSSQL

$query = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE department IN (SELECT id FROM     departments WHERE name='$department') ORDER BY Lastname");
```

Here is how the query is executed:

```
   function listDepts() { 

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM departments ORDER BY name"; 
    $result = mssql_query($query); 
    echo "<h3>Please select a department:</h3>\n"; 
    echo "<ul>\n"; 

    for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
        $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[name]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n"; 
    } 

    echo "</ul>\n\n"; 
}
```

Here is the code that generates the department list.

```
 function listDepts() {

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT  name FROM     departments ORDER BY     name";
$result = mssql_query($query);

echo "<h3>Please select a department:</h3>\n";
echo "<ul>\n";

for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[name]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
}

echo "</ul>\n\n";

 }
```

Comment: Where do you see a SQL special character?

Comment: when it pulls from the table it is having issue with a ' in the department name Women's Softball

Comment: How are you actually executing the query? How are you passing in the parameter?

Comment: This is the code to generate the department links    `function listDepts() {

 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  name FROM     departments ORDER BY     name";
 $result = mssql_query($query);

 echo "<h3>Please select a department:</h3>\n";
 echo "<ul>\n";

 for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
  $info = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "<li><a href=\"dept.php?dept=$info[name]\">$info[name]</a></li>\n";
 }

 echo "</ul>\n\n";

}`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - update your question and post it there - as you can see, all formatting is lost.

Comment: sorry still new to this.

Comment: Not a problem - we were all new here once :)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't select the department by `departments.id`?

Comment: it's pulling from two different tables and the id is just a four letter code for internal purposes

Comment: Inky: njk has a point. You should get both the id and the name when you populate the list. That way you already have the id when you query the `directory` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you use prepared statement and then execute it using the variable:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE department IN (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name=?) ORDER BY Lastname");
if ($stmt->execute(array("Women's Softball coach"))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

See [PHP documentation on prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more info.

In your specific case, you'd have something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE department IN (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name=?) ORDER BY Lastname");
for ($i=0; $i<mssql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    if ($stmt->execute(array($result))) {

        $info = $stmt->fetch(); 
        ...
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is  wouldn't it only take care of that one department. If there are other departments with special characters I would still have the same problem.

Comment: @Inky1231 It would work for all data.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Inky See my updated answer.  You prepare the query once - and then execute it in a loop with repeated parameters.

Comment: trying to get it to work, no success yet but will keep trying.